# Calculate Ratio of multiple pairs of columns

Tags: r

I have a table in R like this one:

```
id  v1  v2  v3
1   115 116 150
2   47  50  55
3   70  77  77
```

I would like to calculate the ratio between v2/v1 as (v2/v1)-1, v3/v2 as (v3/v2)-1 and so on (I have around 55 variables, and need to get values like this:

```
id  v1  v2  v3  rat1    rat2
1   115 116 150 0.01    0.29
2   47  50  55  0.06    0.10
3   70  77  77  0.10    0.00
```

Is there a workaround so I don´t have to code each pair independently?

Thx!

Answer (score 4):

It's essentially a loop over column `i` and column `i+1`, which you could write a `for` loop to do so. Or in R speak, use a vectorised function like `Map`/`mapply`:

```
vars <- paste0("v",1:3)
outs <- paste0("rat",1:2)
dat[outs] <- mapply(`/`, dat[vars[-1]], dat[vars[-length(vars)]]) - 1

dat
#  id  v1  v2  v3        rat1      rat2
#1  1 115 116 150 0.008695652 0.2931034
#2  2  47  50  55 0.063829787 0.1000000
#3  3  70  77  77 0.100000000 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

As we remove equal number of columns from the beginning and end ('id' common), the datasets would still be similar in dimensions, so can directly do a `/`

```
dat[paste0("rat", 1:2)] <- 1- dat[-c(1, ncol(dat))]/dat[-(1:2)]
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(id = 1:3, v1 = c(115L, 47L, 70L), v2 = c(116L, 
50L, 77L), v3 = c(150L, 55L, 77L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```